QGIS GeoJSON Newline Delimited format compatibility with BigQuery
I'm trying to use BigQuery UI to create a table from a GeoJSON file loaded in GCS.

And it looks like the file has been exported successfully from QGIS:

And yet when I go to create a table I still get these errors:

Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://path/world-countries-newlinedelimited.geojsonl.json

Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0

Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Nested arrays not allowed. File: gs://path/world-countries-newlinedelimited.geojsonl.json

Is there something I'm missing? And if not, how can I debug that the file meets BQ's criteria? I looked into this question:
GeoJSON conversion to GeoJSONL BigQuery load error
but I would like to do it either via WebUI or SQL, not bq command line.

Unfortunately, this has to be done in command line.
BigQuery uses --json_extension=GEOJSON option to handle GeoJson correctly (it is different from regular new-line-delimited Json in how Geometry field is located and treated, all properties are nested inside properties element, etc). This option is not exposed in the UI, so you would need to drop to the command line.
See these instructions for details
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#geojson-files
it should be a simple
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --json_extension=GEOJSON \
 --autodetect \
 DATASET.TABLE \
 FILE_PATH_OR_URI


Thank you. I realised that apaqrt from BQ the only other way is to create EXTERNAL TABLE from SQL pointing to the GeoJSON file. Another problem popped up later and it was that BigQuery didn't like hyphens to be in the attribute name so that had to be changed in the attribute table as well
